# Return XML response with metadata from asp .net core Web API

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, xml-serialization

How can I return an XML response from webAPI written in .net core to have the metadata information at the top.

Required response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <metadata>
        <item name="AsOfDate" type="xs:string" length="12"/>
        <item name="RateOfReturn" type="xs:double"/>
        <item name="FamAcctIndex" type="xs:string" length="3"/>
        <item name="RowID" type="xs:string" length="1"/>
        <item name="BrM" type="xs:string" length="1"/>
        <item name="ProductLineCode" type="xs:int"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>Apr 26, 2002</value>
            <value>0.210066429</value>
            <value>JA1</value>
            <value>F</value>
            <value>B</value>
            <value>1</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>Apr 27, 2002</value>
            <value>0.1111111</value>
            <value>BBB</value>
            <value>G</value>
            <value>B</value>
            <value>2</value>
        </row>      
    </data>
</dataset>
```

I have added the following code to accept xml type :

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

My API method returns XML without the metadata if I use `Accept : application/xml`

Comment: @R.Richards - please read through the question before judging it as duplicate. The answer the linked question provides has nothing to do with this question. I am looking at how to include the *metadata* in serialized xml response.

Comment: I apologize! Too quick on the gun.

Comment: Well you gotta write your own serialization, using reflection from the returned model. Technically it should be possible to do this with action filters (if you want to set it on per action or controller base) or as middleware (if you want to apply it to all requests)

Comment: @Tseng - seems possible, no standard way or a library that does that? Or any sample of custom serialization with metadata?

Comment: I fear there is no easy way around it, if you want to keep the metadata. Also an output formatter may be viable option (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/XmlSerializerOutputFormatter.cs  shows the xml formatter, could be applied to xml too), but you'd probably need your own mimetype for it to avoid conflicts to normal xml serializer (in case you want to run both)

Comment: Also if you don't want a custom format, you may want to consider OData. There already an ASP.NET Core compatible version here http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/1.0.0-rtm-00015, though I'm not really sure its the official package, but OData is a more complex format than your sample structure